# Increment a number stored as a list of booleans

Tags: python

In this example I'm iterating over all possible variations of a mask, which I store as a list of booleans

```
Nmax = 32
for num in range (2**Nmax):
    bool_list = [bool(num & (1<<n)) for n in range(Nmax)]
    # other stuff
```

However, the operation to generate `bool_list` is a bit of a bottleneck in the code - the rest is rather fast matrix multiplication. Is there a faster way to increment the number stored in `bool_list` than I'm doing?

Comment: Doing anything 4 billion+ times is going to take a long time, even on modern hardware.  What problem are you trying to solve? You should try to come up with another solution: this one is more or less unworkable.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Not really, it only turns out to be an hour or so for 2^32. Anyway, the precise value of Nmax isn't important to the question I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just taking all combinations of (False, True) `Nmax` times. Hence,

```
from itertools
print(list(itertools.product(*[(False, True)]*Nmax)))
```

will display all the masks.

If you want to use it while iterating,

```
Nmax = 32
masks = itertools.product(*[(False, True)]*Nmax)
for mask in masks:
    # Do stuff
```

Note that `mask` will be a tuple rather than a list.

Comment: `product((False, True), repeat=NMax)` would mean you don't have to build a potentially large list, plus it's a little clearer what you're doing.

Comment: Yep, this seems significantly faster in my testing

Answer (score 0):

For one, I think you can precompute the shifts:

```
Nmax = 32
shifts = [(1 << n) for n in range(Nmax)]
for num in range(2**Nmax):
    bool_list = [bool(num & shift) for shift in shifts]
```